# ReactJs FashRefresh: Lazyload component warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance, build, eslint

I can configure es-lint to hide the warning, but I want to keep this warning to recommend splitting the build file into smaller ones. Do you know what the other solution is?

My eslint warning
[image]

when I build project console warning like this

[image]

My AnSaoTuViPage.tsx

```
import PageContainer from '@/components/PageContainer';

interface AnSaoTuViPageProps {}

const AnSaoTuViPage = (props: AnSaoTuViPageProps) => {
   return <PageContainer title="An Sao Tử Vi">AnSaoTuViPage</PageContainer>;
};

export default AnSaoTuViPage;
```

My Loadable component

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import LoadingIndicator from './LoadingIndicator';

interface Props {
   [key: string]: any;
 }

 type LazyComponent = ReturnType<typeof lazy>;

 const Loadable = (Component: LazyComponent) => (props: Props) => (
  <Suspense fallback={<LoadingIndicator />}>
   <Component {...props} />
  </Suspense>
 );

 export default Loadable;
```

My Routes object

```
import Loadable from '@/components/Loadable';
import { ROUTE_PATH } from '@/constants/route-path';
import { lazy } from 'react';
import { Outlet, RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';

const AnSaoTuViPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import('@/modules/an-sao-tu-vi')));

const anSaoTuViRoutes: RouteObject = {
  path: ROUTE_PATH.AN_SAO_TU_VI,
  element: <Outlet />,
  children: [
    {
      index: true,
      path: '',
      element: <AnSaoTuViPage />,
    },
  ],
};

export default anSaoTuViRoutes;
```